# Input the same formula in excel across multiple worksheets to follow a sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to put the same Excel formula in Excel so that it follows on in the sequence. So `sheet 1` needs to have `='Booking Sheet'!F1` then sheet 2 `='Booking Sheet'!F2` and so on.

Is there a way I can do this without typing it into each worksheet separately as there is 40 sheets and I have to do this with about 75 cells in each sheet.

I was told to hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, highlight all the worksheets and type it in but it doesn't follow the sequence on.

Comment: Do the 40 sheets already exist with data in them, or can those be created automatically? Are the sheets named in a sequential order of some sort? Are you allowed to use helper sheets? Will the formula simply be `='Booking Sheet'!F1`, `='Booking Sheet'!F2`, ..., `='Booking Sheet'!F75` or is there a variation? Is this a one-time thing, or will you do it regularly?

Comment: Ironically, by the time you get an answer, you probably could have done this if it's only 40 sheets!

Comment: you can have a macro that will stick the formula in there for you

Comment: @jmac The 40 sheets already exist there called "Delivery 1 - Delivery 40" they already take data from the booking sheet which I have input into each one manually, I just want to find an easier way. The sheet is used everyday but I will only need to put this formula in once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this macro. It will go through all sheets named `delivery` and put a formula in `A1` that will have a different `F` number for each delivery. So

Sheet `Delivery 1` `A1` will have a formula `='Booking Sheet'F1`

Sheet `Delivery 2` `A1` will have formula =`Booking Sheet'F2`

and so on

```
Sub EnterFormulas()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Delivery", vbTextCompare) Then
            ws.Range("A1").Formula = "='Booking Sheet'!F" & Split(ws.Name, Chr(32))(1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for thread necrophilia but I came across this looking for something similar.  There's a more elegant answer that I'll note here for the record.

Presumably each delivery sheet is pulling data from a list on the booking sheet, hence the sequential 'Booking Sheet'!F1.. F2.. etc

The simplest way is to to give each delivery sheet a unique ref, I guess sequential numbers from 1 to 40.  Also use that ref as the index in the list on the booking sheet.

Then use a lookup formula on the delivery sheet that looks down the list of bookings to find the relevant data. That would allow you to use identical formula on every sheet.

If you are comfortable with macros, you need only have one delivery sheet that you use as a template instead of 40.  Then the macro steps down each row of bookings, populates the delivery sheet, outputs a pdf of the delivery sheet then repeats for each delivery